# Problems with Hearthstone

Tags: games

Okay... So I've been trying to install Hearthstone. But no matter how I do it, it comes out looking like this. So, I need to know what I'm doing wrong. I've tried PlayOnLinux and manual install via the install instructions found here: www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zSQNDvWg80

[image]

Comment: Thank you for showing the screenshot! Said I needed to have  more rep points to do it.

Comment: Still having that same issue. So, if anyone could help, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and i figured out that the problem is with video drivers. So if you want to have better launcher view, you can open terminal ant type:

```
LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program*/Battle.net/"Battle.net Launcher.exe"
```

**Note:** this will work if you installed Hearthstone in default installation location.

P.S. this command will disable text in launcher but you still get better view than before.

If you are running Hearthstone through PlayOnLinux, go to Configure / Miscellaneous / "Command to exec before running the program" and put: export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1